# How toString() overriding works

Tags: java, oop, object, tostring, printstream

I just learnt about the `toString()` method in object class and how to override it in other class.

```
class Box {
      public String toString(){
          return "class Box";
      }
}

class B {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Box b1=new Box();
        System.out.println(b1); //case 1
        Box b2=b1; //case 2
    }
}
```

So my question is how does box object know to return the String in the `toString()` in class Box in case 1 and return the `b1` object's address in case 2?

Comment: This doesn't really have to do with `toString()` overriding, but more with how `System.out.println(Object)` works.

Answer (score 3):

The `System.out.println` method you are calling is the `(Object)` overload, not `(String)`. `PrintStream.println(Object)` calls `toString()` on its argument (pedantry: directly or indirectly, unless the argument is `null`).

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic. If you dig down into the method, eventually `toString` is called explicitly.

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString(); //in your case obj = the box in b1
}
```